# How to use abstract classes in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a game, in the console (it's kinda simple). I want to have multiple types of soldiers, so I thought I'd make an abstract soldier class

```
public abstract class Soldier
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Health;
        public float ShootingRange;
        public float MovementRange;
        public Player Owner;
        public Vector2Int Position;
        public char Symbol;
    }
```

The reason for this is I would like 1 list for all of the units a player has. The player class looks like this:

```
 public class Player
{
    public int Money = 0;
    public ConsoleColor Color;

    public List<Soldiers.Soldier> Units = new List<Soldiers.Soldier>();

    public Player(ConsoleColor c)
    {
        Color = c;
    }

    public void AddUnit(Vector2Int Position)
    {
        Units.Add(new Soldiers.Rifleman(this, Position));
    }
}
```

Then I wanted to implement a version of the Soldier class to make a kind of soldier I call it Rifleman:

```
public class Rifleman : Soldier
    {
        public int Health = 10;
        public float ShootingRange = 5f;
        public float MovementRange = 2.5f;
        public Player Owner;
        public Vector2Int Position;
        public char Symbol = Utils.MASTERKEY["Rifleman"];

        public Rifleman(Player owner, Vector2Int position)
        {
            Owner = owner;
            Position = position;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that in my map class (how I display and manage the game) when I go to try and pull the char representing the Rifleman class on the map, it finds it to be a null value. How could I fix this?

Comment: You want properties instead of fields

Comment: Your `Rifleman` class defines its own `Symbol` field, even though your base class already has one. Use the one from the base class instead. Same for all the other fields/properties.

Comment: @Progman is right.  You should be getting a compiler warning about declaring a new field with the same name.  Don't add new fields, just assign values in the constructor.

Comment: **Pay attention to compiler warnings**. You should have gotten a warning from the compiler telling you that you were doing something that looked wrong. That warning was correct, and would have helped you diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Progman and @bmm6o said, you're redefining your `Symbol` field. Since your `List<Soldier>` returns a `Soldier`, its `Symbol` field is what you're getting, which wasn't assigned.

You should either be using abstract and/or virtual properties you can override, or protected setter properties like either in the examples below showing different forms.

```cs
public abstract Soldier
{
  public abstract char Symbol { get; }
  public virtual string Name { get; } = "Soldier";
  public string Weapon { get; protected set; } = "Gun";
}

public Rifleman : Soldier
{
  public override char Symbol => 'r';
  public override string Name => nameof(Rifleman);
}

public Sniper : Soldier
{
  public Solder()
  {
    Weapon = "Rifle";
  }
  public override char Symbol => 's';
}
```

Fields should almost always be private, and are often unnecessary in modern versions of C# (what you see above are language features that should work with any .NET Framework or Core version).